# knexfile.js equivalent in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a file that was originally written in C#. As of now it is broken. The current errors are "X" table was not found, "X" table was not found, "X" table was not found.

Due to security reasons, I am unable to post snippets of the code or give detailed information.

My thought process is that the DB is corrupt or not connected to the file. I am trying to find a knexfile.js equivalent in C#.

Sorry for the limited information.

I've looked online and can only find JS equivalents to common C# methods.

Comment: Your problem is not entirely clear. `I have a file that was originally written in C#` - when you say that you have a file, do you mean: 1) a .CS file? 2) an .EXE originally written in C#? 3) something else? Can you provide additional details?

Comment: It is an entire project written in .cs.

Comment: The problem may not be clear, but the requirement is: "I am trying to find a knexfile.js equivalent in C#". We don't need more details for that. The problem may help to suggest another tool, but it is not stopping you from answering the need. In my case, unfortunately, don't know a query builder like Knex, some time ago I was looking for one too, without luck.